# Json.deserialize in Apex

Tags: apex

I have an exceptional case. My json contains key with a space in it. Since the json is provided by a third party and used widely,i cannot change the incoming json. How can i de-serialize this? Example is below

Assume i have a class like below..

```
class b{
    Integer a;
}
```

How can i structure the above class to deserialize the below json. ?

```
System.debug(Json.deserialize('{"a b":1}', b.class));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the deserializeUntyped() method you could get the JSON string converted into a `map<String,Object>`, and then get the property value with that string key.

```
Map<String,Object> apexmap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped('{"a b":1}');

system.debug(apexmap.get('a b'));
```