# Parse Json string to Salesforce object?

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

How to map json string with salesforce object(consider Lead)??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.deserialize in Apex](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91962/json-deserialize-in-apex)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an auxiliar class with the fields that you have on the Json like for example

```
public with sharing Class LeadHelper {
    public String FXRating {get;set;}
    public String Status {get;set;}
    public String AnalyticsId {get;set;}
    public String AccountBussinessID {get;set;}
    public String source {Get;set;}

    LeadHelper(Lead L){
        AccountBussinessID = (L.isConverted)? String.valueOf(L.ConvertedAccountID):'';
        FXRating = (L.FXRatingLetter__c=='A+')? 'A%2B' :L.FXRatingLetter__c;
        Status = L.Lead_Status_GA__c;
        AnalyticsId = L.analytics_id__c;
    }
   }
```

Then you do a convert of the Json to this auxiliar class

```
  LeadHelper  Lead_converted = (LeadHelper) JSON.deserialize(LeadToSend);
```

then you just have to create a new lead and map the fields.

```
Lead L = new Lead (FirstName = Lead_converted.name or whatever field you want)
```

I just pointed general tips, but I think they should be enogh to help you.

If you still have any doubts comment below.

**EDIT:**
okei So i would create this

```
public with sharing Class JsonLead {
    public String id {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
   }
```

then  lets say you declare your

```
JsonLead newJsonLead = (JsonLead) JSON.deserialize(name of the variable you have your Json stored in);
Lead L = new Lead (id=newJsonLead.id, Name = newJsonLead.Name);
// DO WHATEVER EXTRA YOU NEED TO DO HERE
update L;
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
    private static void sendInfoToGA (List<String> LeadsToInsert) {
List <Lead> leads = new List <lead> ();
JsonLead LeadToInsert;      
            while(!LeadsToInsert.isEmpty()) {
                    LeadToInsert = (JsonLead) JSON.deserialize(LeadsToInsert[0], JsonLead.class);
                   Lead L = new Lead (id=LeadToinsert.id, Name = LeadToinsert.Name);    
    leads.add(L);
                    LeadsToInsert.remove(0);

                }
    insert leads;
```

Comment: Thanks for replay! Now i want to make update this json lead info into Lead object.. how can i workout for this function?

Comment: I suppose you're getting this leadJson info from some kind of Callout, you just have to create that JsonLead class (leadHelper in my case) on your class , and do as I said on my previous comment, then create the lead, copy the fields into it and insert/update normally like in any other apex code. 

Could you please paste your code so I can get more into context and give you a more precise answer. 

Thanks!

Comment: yes i'm getting json from external system! 

{  "Id": "1234",  "Name": "Test Lead"}

I want to update json id with Lead_ID__c and name with Name

Comment: Look my edit. Hope this helps.

Comment: Almost done! For one record it's Ok here!! But if i have 100s of records so i want to iterate and map the fields..

Comment: I will edit my comment and paste a copy of my code where I iterate over a List <JsonLead> , they have obviously other names but it should still help you get the idea :)